# I Tried Downloading A Video Using Internet Download Manager, But It Failed

Tags: video, internet, video-streaming

I want to download this video - http://animax.mn:12000/?media=rencoded/op/one_piece503.mp4

[Here is a link to a page with similar videos](https://animax.mn/anime/watch/3460). I tried to download the video using [Internet Download Manager](https://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/), but it failed, as shown in this screenshot

[image: Internet Download Manager Failed Screenshot]

Is it possible to save this video for offline viewing? Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

---

*Note that the website in question (`http://animax.mn`) seems to be non-operational as of June 2021)*

---

The issue you are likely encountering is that the site uses special cookies, which Internet Download Manager probably isn't sending. Particularly, these include a CSRF token to protect against [cross-site request forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)
attacks and a [Laravel PHP Framework](https://laravel.com/) session ID. These need be transmitted with the request for the file or the request will be refused.

To download the video, you can:

- See if there is an option to include these or otherwise add cookies to Internet Download Manager.
- Use another tool that can download files as well as handle cookies (such as [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)).

Assuming Internet Download Manager doesn't support any additional options to help download this video, you can try the basic instructions for cURL given below.

---

**Getting cURL**

cURL can be downloaded from its [official download page](https://curl.se/download.html). The Windows builds are near the very bottom. The blue version numbers link to
the appropriate files to download. The blue personal names typically lead elsewhere.

<strike>As a suggestion, you may wish to use one of the current (as of this writing) v7.59.0 builds by Viktor Szakats (either the Win32 or Win64 version, as appropriate).</strike>

*Update:*

The Viktor Szakats builds have apparently been supplanted by the [official Windows builds of cURL](https://curl.se/windows/) (which are still recommended and available in 32-bit/64-bit versions).

Once downloaded, simply unzip the file and place the contents in a permanent folder of your choosing. To avoid having to use the full path to `curl.exe` every time you use cURL, you will likely want to register `curl.exe` in your Windows `Path` (`curl.exe` is located in the `bin` folder <strike>for the Szakats builds</strike> for the official Windows builds).

**Getting The Cookies**

You can likely use your browser to get the necessary CSRF token and Laravel session ID to use with cURL (or whichever program you choose) through the developer's console included with modern Chromium-style browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, etc.). As an added benefit, by following the steps below, you can get your basic cURL command as well...

*"Copy as cURL" Steps:*

1. Login to the website as normal.
2. Go to a video page ([such as one of the ones listed in this link from your question](https://animax.mn/anime/watch/3460)).
3. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> in Opera) to open the developer's console and select the *Network* option on the right.
   For ease of use, I would also suggest you click the small *Show in separate windows* icon (on the far right) to separate the console from the main browser window.

*ex.* *Network Option and Separate Console*
[image: Developer's Console Network And Docking Options]

4. Reload the video page but do not close the console. The console will capture network traffic related to the page, including the HTTP [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) request for e.g. http://animax.mn:12000/?media=rencoded/op/one_piece503.mp4
   (which would appear as `GET /?media=rencoded/op/one_piece503.mp4`).
5. There will be a large number of `GET` requests, so you will likely want to filter them with the *Media* sub-option. You can preview cookies by selecting the *Cookies* option of the `GET` request as well.

*ex.* *Media Filtering and Cookie Preview*
[image: Developer's Console Media Filter and Cookie Options]

6. Right-click the appropriate `GET` request and select the *Copy as cURL* menu option (likely *Copy as cURL (cmd)* in Chrome). Paste the resulting command into Notepad or similar (it will *not* be displayed beforehand).

*ex.* *Copy As cURL - Firefox*
[image: Developer's Console Copying GET Request As Curl]

With the video links given, I didn't have any issue with `GET` requests appearing immediately. However, if the *Media* filter option is blank, you should use the console *Clear* (Trashcan) icon on the far left then press the "play" button of the media player in the main window (where the video appears normally). This should make any appropriate `GET` request(s) for the media file(s) in question appear.

**Inspecting The cURL Request**

The text you've copied should look similar to the following:

> curl http://animax.mn:12000/?media=rencoded/op/one_piece001.mp4 -H "Host: animax.mn:12000" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0" -H "Accept: video/webm,video/ogg,video/*;q=0.9,application/ogg;q=0.7,audio/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5" -H "Range: bytes=0-" -H "Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkE0WlRudGtmdUlhQWRUTUFndkFPelE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiXC95dmFPeGdkWTN6QmZTamNXTUF0MFJOSitHWXdxOE1kRHRQeGVHWURmbVRuWG4zU0lFSW5IZEVpcFwvYzlQandDeUd4cGlkUzVtZk1PaEs2dzRoaDlRUT09IiwibWFjIjoiMDdjNjNmYTFhOWM5MzhlYmFjNTk5ZmRmNzNiN2IxYTc2ZWJlOWM3MjVlZDM5YWY4ZDQxYTdmMjNjNzNjOWI3MCJ9; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjN0VTlEQStvdyt0NXdMeDdTaUhJOUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibXhMQ1dLMFl3M0FUSTlIKzVxcjRqTnpncFFJRGhrZktCaThKeHZxRXRmU1M5VXFWSjR0bjJIKzRHWE1VWFpxNUp3QTNZSW1ZXC9vaW1DaEdGU0k2dCtRPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI0YzYxOTI3ZjRiZTYzZGNkZmZkZmY1YjhjOWMzZGJmM2I1N2EyMjE4ODU1ODkwMGRmYjFhOThjOWZlNmRiZDhkIn0"%"3D; wh-widget-cookie=1" -H "DNT: 1" -H "Connection: keep-alive"

If you need just the CSRF token and Laravel session ID, you can eliminate most of the copied command, leaving just e.g.:

> "XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkE0WlRudGtmdUlhQWRUTUFndkFPelE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiXC95dmFPeGdkWTN6QmZTamNXTUF0MFJOSitHWXdxOE1kRHRQeGVHWURmbVRuWG4zU0lFSW5IZEVpcFwvYzlQandDeUd4cGlkUzVtZk1PaEs2dzRoaDlRUT09IiwibWFjIjoiMDdjNjNmYTFhOWM5MzhlYmFjNTk5ZmRmNzNiN2IxYTc2ZWJlOWM3MjVlZDM5YWY4ZDQxYTdmMjNjNzNjOWI3MCJ9; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjN0VTlEQStvdyt0NXdMeDdTaUhJOUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibXhMQ1dLMFl3M0FUSTlIKzVxcjRqTnpncFFJRGhrZktCaThKeHZxRXRmU1M5VXFWSjR0bjJIKzRHWE1VWFpxNUp3QTNZSW1ZXC9vaW1DaEdGU0k2dCtRPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI0YzYxOTI3ZjRiZTYzZGNkZmZkZmY1YjhjOWMzZGJmM2I1N2EyMjE4ODU1ODkwMGRmYjFhOThjOWZlNmRiZDhkIn0"%"3D"

Note that you should be able to safely eliminate the `; wh-widget-cookie=1"` portion at the end of of the cookies, as shown above (this last cookie doesn't seem necessary for connections via cURL). Be aware, however, and keep the double quotes surrounding the cookies unless you determine that they aren't actually needed.

**Downloading With cURL**

As is, the command you initially copied has (almost) all the data needed to make a request for e.g. *http://animax.mn:12000/?media=rencoded/op/one_piece503.mp4*. You just need to add the `-O` (captial oh) output option just after `curl` and the correct URL (as needed) e.g.:

> curl -O "http://animax.mn:12000/?media=rencoded/op/one_piece503.mp4" -H "Host: animax.mn:12000" [...] -H "Connection: keep-alive"

(To be clear,  the ellipses `[...]` are just my shorthand — you would include the full remaining text of the copied command, shown earlier).

You could then (hopefully) run this cURL command from the command line to download the video.

**Shortening The Command**

In this instance, the default cURL command has a lot of extraneous pieces. If you feel the need, the cURL command can be shortened to just e.g.:

> curl -O http://animax.mn:12000/?media=rencoded/op/one_piece503.mp4 -r 0- --cookie "XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkE0WlRudGtmdUlhQWRUTUFndkFPelE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiXC95dmFPeGdkWTN6QmZTamNXTUF0MFJOSitHWXdxOE1kRHRQeGVHWURmbVRuWG4zU0lFSW5IZEVpcFwvYzlQandDeUd4cGlkUzVtZk1PaEs2dzRoaDlRUT09IiwibWFjIjoiMDdjNjNmYTFhOWM5MzhlYmFjNTk5ZmRmNzNiN2IxYTc2ZWJlOWM3MjVlZDM5YWY4ZDQxYTdmMjNjNzNjOWI3MCJ9; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjN0VTlEQStvdyt0NXdMeDdTaUhJOUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibXhMQ1dLMFl3M0FUSTlIKzVxcjRqTnpncFFJRGhrZktCaThKeHZxRXRmU1M5VXFWSjR0bjJIKzRHWE1VWFpxNUp3QTNZSW1ZXC9vaW1DaEdGU0k2dCtRPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI0YzYxOTI3ZjRiZTYzZGNkZmZkZmY1YjhjOWMzZGJmM2I1N2EyMjE4ODU1ODkwMGRmYjFhOThjOWZlNmRiZDhkIn0"%"3D" -H "Connection: keep-alive"

As a quick point, `-r 0-` takes the place of `-H "Range: bytes=0-` (in this case, the `Range:` header is the only other component of the original URL needed by cURL besides the given cookies).

**Notes**

- I encountered no errors regarding re-using the same cookies for multiple videos over the same session. However, note that logging out/logging in will change the cookies and you will have to perform the steps I outline to regather them each time you do so.
- You may want to disable your anti-virus, etc. (temporarily) for downloads
- It probably isn't necessary to keep the https://animax.mn browser window open but I would just so I could log out when finished (or possibly re-login). It seems unclear what the session handling criteria generally is for the site otherwise.
- You can take (almost?) the same cookies from the initial login `POST` request, but it seemed like there may have been some small, unconfirmed issues with that (which is why I recommend taking them directly from the `GET` request).
- You'll likely want to be careful with copying the cookies. They can be a bit unwieldy with normal cut/paste operations.

---

**Optimism vs. Pessimism**

*"The optimist proclaims that we live in the best of all possible worlds; and the pessimist fears this is true."*

Unfortunately, while testing this answer, I was unable to *completely* download any video (though partial downloads did work up to the point where they were broken). I suspect a poor network connection and (possibly) poor site design led to the aborted downloads (anecdotally, I encountered several PHP errors unrelated to cURL just browsing the site).

So your mileage with cURL and your chosen site may vary...

---